# Create a repeating timer for a Live Activity

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

In a Live Activity or in a Dynamic Island is easy to create a timer. For instance:

```
Text(Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 60), style: .timer)
```

will create a 60 seconds timer counting from when the code was first run.

What I could not do is create a repeating timer, where when it gets to 00:00 it would reset back to the initial value (60 seconds in the example) *ad infinitum*.

Answer (score -2):

Use `onReceive` to measure the value every second and set it back to 60 seconds when it becomes 0.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var timeRemaining = 60
    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()

    var body: some View {
        Text("\(timeRemaining)")
            .onReceive(timer) { _ in
                if self.timeRemaining > 0 {
                    self.timeRemaining -= 1
                } else {
                    timeRemaining = 60
                }
            }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: It could have been a good idea but it doesn't work. Probably because is running inside an extension to update a SwiftUI widget.